# cakephp - get rows from other table

Tags: cakephp

In moviesController i have a public function add() which normally needs to work with data from Movies table. (For example i can do $this->Movie->findById($id); or $this->Movie->save(); )

In the add view I have a form which takes input from a user and save it into database.
All that works just fine.

But i would like to change this form a little, so there will be a list of genres (action, comedy, etc) and user will be able to select many of them.
For now i just have an array with genre values which are used to populate checkboxes but I need to get this values from a table.

So the question I'm asking is, what is the way to get rows from other table Genres in moviesController in public function add() so i can populate a form list while still using main table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your Movies Controller:

```
<?php 
class MoviesController extends AppController {
  // here you select wath models you want to use
  public $uses = array("Movie", "Genre");


  public function add() {
    // Here you get genre list ids and names
    $genreList =  $this->Genre->find("list", array());

  }
}
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Yea I know about associations and I'm using them generally, but just in this case I didnt think I would need them cause its so simple. Is it possible to alter $hasMany in Controller? Cause I just tried to add 'Genre' => array('className' => 'Genre') to existent $hasMany in the Movie Model and it works great for that specific view :) but sadly, everything else on the site related to MovieController fell apart :D cause it reports error with 'column not found etc'

Comment: better now? or i not undertanding?

Comment: Oups I was replying to your earlier comment. OMg yes this '$public uses ...' works! thank you :)

Comment: I am assuming `Movie` and `Genre` are associated in some way, in which case you can simply do `$this->Movie->Genre->find('list');`.

Answer (score 0):

If your `Movies` model has any relationship with `Genre`, you can just do this:

```
$this->set('genre', $this->Movie->Genre->find('list'));
```

In your view, you can do something like this (pseudocode):

```
<?php
    echo $this->Form->input('Movie.Genre', array(
        'options' => $genre,
        'type' => 'select',
        'multiple' => 'checkbox',
        'class' => '',
        'label' => array('class' => 'control-label', 'text' => "Genre:"),
        'after' => ''
    ));
?>
```

Update:

Of course `Movie` should have a has_many relationship with `Genre`.

Comment: And for this you should add  hasMany or belongs to to your Movies Model :)

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/associations-linking-models-together.html

Comment: @GonzaloBahamondez, anyway, I will just add it :)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But what if these two tables don't have any relationship? :) Table Genres is a lonely table with only a list of values, there are no foreign keys...

Comment: No matter if you don have foreign keys , cake php do this for you using has many and belongs to, but every time is better use foreign keys. Read hasMany and belogsTo directives from cakephp documentation.

Comment: @Marko, you should have them. It is gonna be weird if you have a Movie related to Genre without `foreign keys`.